# How to globally set option for each child?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have class form with a few of child:

```
class ReservationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('from', DateType::class, ["label" => "reservation.from?", "widget" => "single_text", "error_bubbling" => true]);
        $builder->add('to', DateType::class, ["label" => "reservation.to?", "widget" => "single_text", "error_bubbling" => true]);
        $builder->add("name", TextType::class, ["label" => "reservation.name", "error_bubbling" => true]);
        $builder->add("surname", TextType::class, ["label" => "reservation.surname", "error_bubbling" => true]);
        $builder->add('book', SubmitType::class, ["label" => "reservation.booking"]);
    }
}
```

I individually set `error_bubling` option to each of child. It's work properly.
I'am pretty sure there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the [Form Extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html), but it will affect **all** forms

```
namespace App\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class ErrorBublingExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        return [DateType::class, TextType::class];
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'error_bubbling' => true,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Tested, and it works :) But as you mentioned its effect all forms. **It's huge flaw**.